# How to reshape a 2d numpy.array or Qobj into dims=[[2,2],[2,2]]

Tags: python, reshape, qutip

Numpy example below

---

### Goal: QuTiP object

The goal of my request is to add two quantum state objects of type `Qobj` (density matrices) as in the following example of a Werner state (to give it some physical meaning).

```
import qutip as q
r = .5
state = r * q.ket2dm(q.ghz_state(2)) + (1-r) * q.maximally_mixed_dm(4)
```

The error message is

```
TypeError: Incompatible quantum object dimensions
```

So one could go to the lower dimensional state but then we loose the relevant dimension properties to proceed with the state:

```
state = r * q.ket2dm(q.ghz_state(2)).data.toarray() + (1-r) * q.maximally_mixed_dm(4)
```

My attempts like `q.Qobj(q.maximally_mixed_dm(4).data.toarray().reshape([[2,2],[2,2]]))` all failed as reshape does not handle lists of lists.

The inverse going from dimensions `[[2,2],[2,2]]` down to `[4,4]` is not a miracle using reshape or as shown by the conversion to an array.
But is the inverse implemented in either numpy nor qutip?

---

### Edit: For people familiar with numpy

How do you reshape a 2d array (e.g. here 4x4) in to a (2x2)x(2x2) one?
The built in function of numpy seems to dislike my requested example.
It does not accept lists of lists as shown here:

```
import numpy as np
state = np.identity(4).reshape([[2,2],[2,2]])
```

I was surprised that no one ever asked this question before!

Comment: How does `[[2,2],[2,2]]` shape look like? How is it different from `[2, 2, 2, 2]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using reshape in the wrong way. It takes a tuple of the dimensions as an argument (see the docs) and not a tuple of tuples or list of lists with the dimensions as elements - how should that work? I think you are mixing the depth of your list of lists with the dimensionality (which are expected to be the numeric entries of the tuple).

I am not sure what exactly you wanna end up with but I guess one of the following:

```
state = np.identity(4).reshape((2,2,2,2))
state = np.identity(4).reshape((4,2,2))
state = np.identity(4).reshape((2,2,4))
```

Answer (score 3):

Jojo's answer is incomplete when it comes to applying this answer to qutip.

### Qutip specific problem

The confusing part about qutip was that it requires a shape of (4,4) but the quantum dimensions are `[[2,2],[2,2]]`.
This results in error messages like either if the shape is correct, the quantum dimensions are wrong:

```
>>> import qutip as q
>>> s1 = q.ket2dm(q.ghz_state(2))
>>> s2 = q.maximally_mixed_dm(4).data.toarray().reshape((4,4))
>>> s1+s2

TypeError: Incompatible quantum object dimensions
```

or if the quantum dimension is accepted, the internal shape is wrong:

```
>>> import qutip as q
>>> s1 = q.ket2dm(q.ghz_state(2))
>>> s2 = q.maximally_mixed_dm(4).data.toarray().reshape((2,2,2,2))
>>> s1+s2

TypeError: expected dimension <= 2 array or matrix
```

### Qutip specific conversion

The solution is to reconvert the correct shape (4,4) to the right quantum dimensions `[[2,2],[2,2]]`:

```
s2 = q.Qobj(q.maximally_mixed_dm(4).data.toarray().reshape((4,4)),
            dims=[[2,2],[2,2]])
```

Unfortunately I don't see currently such an implementation in qutip but this "workaround" via numpy works.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dimensions directly with the dims attribute:

```
s2 = q.maximally_mixed_dm(4)
s2.dims = [[2,2],[2,2]]
```